# Up navigation broken on JellyBean?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Source code is available here: https://github.com/novemberox/NavigationTest It's modified version of this sample: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

I've got three activities:

- `Main Activity` just main entry to application
- `Category Activity` it's parent for Detail Activity
- `Detail Activity`

`Main Activity` has button that opens `Category Activity` and `Detail Activity`. 
`Category Activty` has just one button that opens `Detail Activity`.
And finally `Detail Activity` that shows some text and has up button that simulates click on ActionBar up.

My "clicking" path is:

- open Main Activity
- open Detail Activity
- click "up button"
- Category Activty should appear
- back click moves us to Main Activity with state restored

And this is flow that is would be expecting and it's working just fine on every Android before Jelly Bean (tested on Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1 and emulator 4.2 Google exp pack). It works even on ICS. I'm using support lib and classes like NavUtils and TaskStackBuilder, like in sample that I pointed at beginning.

On JB when I click "up button" it goes back to Main Activity with state restored correctly. I looked into source code of support library and I saw that `NavUtils.navigateUpTo` method calls native JB code like `Activity#navigateUpTo`. I tried both `NavUtils#navigateUpTo()` and `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask()` with the same unsatisfactory result.

Do you have some suggestion what to do to have this nice flow?

Answer (score 63):

First things first, if you are targeting devices as high as API 17 (Android 4.2), set the `targetSdkVersion` to 17 in your manifest. This doesn't break support for old devices, it just makes things work properly for newer devices. Of course, that doesn't fix your problem -- it's just good to do it.

### What Should You Use?

I assume you are basing your code off of the Ancestral Navigation example on [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html). You've used the second example:

```
Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MyParentActivity.class);
if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
    // This activity is not part of the application's task, so create a new task
    // with a synthesized back stack.
    TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
        .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MyGreatGrandParentActivity.class))
        .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MyGrandParentActivity.class))
        .addNextIntent(upIntent)
        .startActivities();
    finish();
 } else {
     // This activity is part of the application's task, so simply
     // navigate up to the hierarchical parent activity.
     NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
 }
```

For the behavior you want, however, you would need to replace `NavUtils.navigateUpTo` with:

```
upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(upIntent);
finish();
```

### Why does it work on ICS and Earlier?

In general, the support library is trying to **approximate** the behavior introduced in later APIs. In the case of `NavUtils`, the support library is trying to approximate the bahavior introduced in API 16 (a.k.a. Android 4.1). For pre-API 16 platforms, [NavUtils](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/57ff0548ba991652576d81adaaa8baf4c028de39/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.java) uses:

```
@Override
public void navigateUpTo(Activity activity, Intent upIntent) {
    upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    activity.startActivity(upIntent);
    activity.finish();
}
```

This looks through the back stack for an instance of the activity specified in `upInent`. If it finds one, it clears everything up to it and restores it. Otherwise it just launches the activity.

On API 16+ later platforms, the support library hands things off to the native call in the `Activity` API. According to the docs:

> public boolean navigateUpTo (Intent upIntent)
>
> Navigate from this activity to the activity specified by upIntent, finishing this activity in the process. If the activity indicated by upIntent already exists in the task's history, this activity and all others before the indicated activity in the history stack will be finished.
>
> **If the indicated activity does not appear in the history stack, this will finish each activity in this task until the root activity of the task is reached**, resulting in an "in-app home" behavior. This can be useful in apps with a complex navigation hierarchy when an activity may be reached by a path not passing through a canonical parent activity.

From that, it is unclear whether or not it will launch the activity specified in `upIntent` if it is not in the back stack. Reading [the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L4965) doesn't help clarify things either. However, judging from the behavior your app is showing, it appears that it **does not** attempt to launch the `upIntent` activity.

Regardless of which implementation is right or wrong, the end result is that you want the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` behavior, not the native API 16 behavior. Unfortunately this means that you will have to duplicate the support library approximation.

### Which is Correct?

Disclaimer: I don't work for Google, so this is my best guess.

My guess is that the API 16+ behavior is the intended behavior; it's a builtin implementation that has access to the Android internals and can do things that are not possible through the API. Pre-API 16, I don't think it was possible to unwind the backstack in this fashion other than by using intent flags. Thus, the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag is the **closest approximation** of the API 16 behavior available to pre-API 16 platforms.

Unfortunately the result is that between the native implementation and the support library implementation there is a violation of the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) in your scenario. That leads me to wonder if this is an unanticipated use of the API. I.e., I wonder if Android expects that you to traverse the full navigation path to an activity, not jump directly to it.

### Just in Case

Just to avoid one possible misconception, it is possible that someone might expect `shouldUpRecreateTask` to magically determine that the parent isn't in the back stack and go through the process of synthesizing everything for you using the `TaskStackBuilder`.

However, `shouldUpRecreateTask` basically determines if your activity was launched directly by your app (in which case it returns `false`), or if it was launched from another app (in which case it returns `true`). From [this book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=6aGS01sC33gC&pg=PA660&lpg=PA660&dq=android+shoulduprecreatetask&source=bl&ots=gdWuFMWdp2&sig=M9m-AZ6fUt4MK8t1vs21sFSo72g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cMMWUf73IuiKiAKp9YEg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=android%20shoulduprecreatetask&f=false), the support library checks if the intent's "action" is not `ACTION_MAIN` (I don't fully understand that), whereas on API 16 platforms it performs this check based on task affinity. Still, in the case of this app, things work out to `shouldUpRecreateTask` returning false.

Comment: I know that `shouldUpRecreateTask` returns false and why and that is fine. Problem is in `NavUtils.navigateUpTo`. I'm not sure if this behavior is intended? Why Google makes that the same method works differently on different apis? How should I manage my application navigation to be consistent here?

Comment: I've added some more explanatory comments to my answer, though in the end I still can't tell you if the Android API or the Support Library API is wrong. You can report a bug to the [official Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) to see if they can shed more light on it. Still, if you want something that works for the present time, manually launching the parent activity intent using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cannot accept answer since it doesn't do it, but bounty is for you.

Comment: @Mikooos I gave my answer one last revision with a stronger emphasis on why the two implementations might be different. At the end of the day though, I don't work for Google, so it's my best guess. Sorry I can't offer you anything more concrete.

Comment: Having the exact same problem, I'm using your suggestion now and it works like it would have been expected with `NavUtils.navigateUpTo`. Thanks for this great answer!

Comment: As a note: you can get parent activity for own `navigateUpTo` implementation using `NavUtils#getParentActivityIntent(Activity)`

Comment: I used android:launchMode="singleTop" and it is working fine now :)

Comment: There is no need to call finish() as the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP automatically shuts down the activity which is launching the Intent.

Comment: @kpsfoo That is only true if the activity specified by upIntent already exists in the back stack; otherwise FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP effectively does nothing.

Comment: @cyfur01, Agreed, I assumed that most people do not mess up the back stack while making the above comment.

Comment: This "flaw" still happens with `navigateUpTo` on API 24. Has anyone found any indication in the guides/best practices that an UP nav button (i.e. with actionbar.setHomeAsUpEnabled) should EVER do anything other than go to the parent activity declared in the manifest (or even whatever intent you return with `getparentActivityIntent`?

Answer (score 0):

After reading @cyfur01's answer, I came up with very simple solution that fixes the behavior.

Override this method in your Activity (or ideally in some BaseActivity to have it fixed for all subclasses) and it should work as expected:

```
@Override
public boolean navigateUpTo(Intent upIntent) {
    boolean result = super.navigateUpTo(upIntent);
    if (!result) {
        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
            .startActivities();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It leaves all work to Android implementation and then just checks return value of `navigateUpTo(upIntent)` which is `false` when *an instance of the indicated activity could not be found and this activity was simply finished normally*. Which is exactly the case when we want to create and start the parent Activities manually. Also note we don't have to call `finish()` here as it was called by the super method.