# ActionBar Up Button not going where expected on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock

I have 4 Activities, like so :

```
MainActivity -> Activity B -> Activity C
              \ Activity A /
```

The Activity on the left is the right Activity's parent.

I'm using SherlockActionBar to provide the up navigation.

The "default" path is `MainActivity -> Activity B > Activity C` and it works perfectly on every phone, I can go up `C > B > Main`.

On Android 2.3, When I'm going `Main > A > C`, the up navigation goes `C > B > Main`, which is expected.

On Android 4.1.2 (Galaxy S3), with the same path `Main > A > C`, the up navigation does `C > Main`, it totally misses the `Activity B`, the logical parent.

Here is a some of my `AndroidManifest.xml` (I removed the package name)

```
    <activity
        android:name="my.package.ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_a"
        android:parentActivityName="my.package.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="my.package.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="my.package.ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_b"
        android:parentActivityName="my.package.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="my.package.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="my.package.ActivityC"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_c"
        android:parentActivityName="my.package.ActivityB" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="my.package.ActivityB" />
    </activity>
```

I don't know if I made myself clear enough, Here is someone having the same problem : [Confused by ActionBar UP navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675674/confused-by-actionbar-up-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Tab navigation then below code can help you:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener{

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
          actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
          actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
          tab=actionBar.newTab();
          tab.setText("HOME");
          tab.setTabListener(this);
          actionBar.addTab(tab);

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case android.R.id.home:
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
                }else{
                    Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                }
            return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```