# Up Navigation not working

Tags: android

So I'm following the lesson on this link
 http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html 
in order to get the Up Navigation working. I have the exact same code.

The issue is when I tap on the bar it gives me the msg "Unfortunately, "app" stopped working", and then takes me to the main activity (the parent activity).

I'm running the app on my Note 3 LTE device on 4.3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602283/up-navigation-broken-on-jellybean check this out

Comment: It totally worked, How do I mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code provided on your link.
A possible problem may be that you have not declared the `Activity` that you put the `upNavigation` in the `Manifest.xml`. Please post your code and `LogCat`, since I cannot say what the problem is for sure.