# Handling Up Navigation for an Activity which has mutiple starting point - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, up-navigation

I have three activities Activity A, B and C. Activity C can be launched from Activity A and also from Activity B.

Now, the up navigation button on Activity C should take me to that activity which started it. Since the parent activity for C is dynamic I cannot specify the `parentActivity` in the activity tag of C inside the manifest file.

How can I handle up `UpNavigation` for an Activity whose parent activity changes ?

**Edit**

The following SO question is somewhat similar to mine but the answer made me understand the concept correctly.
[Here is that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602283/up-navigation-broken-on-jellybean/14792752#14792752)

Comment: pass activity name with intent...and finish the parent activity..on up navigation start that activity again

Comment: Does android not taking care of it?

Comment: @MeenalSharma okay but why do I need to finish the parent activity ?

Comment: as you need to start it again

Comment: @Praveen it does not happens in up navigation only on back button. And also I am using android support library to support up navigation for older devices.

Comment: @MeenalSharma For that I think we can use addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: I think I found a better SO question with more detailed answer which I was looking for I will update the question with the link to that question

Comment: yes we can..just give it a try..btw it will finish activity C..if u dnt need it..u can use this flag..

Comment: @MeenalSharma yup, thanks though :)